# Android Reachability test

Tags: java, android, reachability

I have an issue regarding how to check the reachability of a certain url. I can do it with a httpget url connection.

```
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(HOST_URL);
HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
int timeoutConnection = 5000;
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
int timeoutSocket = 8000;
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
```

But i want to do it with this way.

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) TabViewActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
boolean test = cm.requestRouteToHost(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI,
                            lookupHost(HOST_IP));
```

But the problem is the boolean always returns flase.

If you have any ideas about this issue it will be a big help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please take more care when formatting posts.

Comment: Sorry abrok, My bad. It was okay until i press the ctrl + k. Then it got messed up. the code tag did not work as it should.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`requestRouteToHost` doesnt work with `type_wifi`**

`requestRouteToHost` method returns the integer value correctly since it works with `type_mobile`.

`Type_wifi` is the one which it doesnt work with.

Nevertheless You need permissions :

```
ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE

ACCESS_WIFI_STATE
```

Comment: hey sherif, I have given those permissions. And i dont get any permission related errors.

Comment: Are you sure you are connected to wifi? Maybe u need to check the network! and not wifi

Comment: Yes, Im connected to wifi. And i tried with mobile network as you suggested. It works and returns true. But it doesnt seem to work with WIFI.

Comment: lookupHost implementation and what is HOST_IP 's value?

Comment: the method returns the integer value correctly since it works with type_mobile. Type_wifi is the one which it doesnt work with. After searching in the net, i found that the requestRouteToHost doesnt work with type_wifi.

Comment: Great :D I will add this info to the answer